# table-cell span wrong height

Tags: html, css

I have this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X7pa3/1/), what is going on, the span is bigger than it should be.

**HTML**

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="input-group-addon rounded-left" placeholder="Search for music">
     <span class="input-group-addon">test</span>
     <span class="input-group-addon rounded-right">search</span>       
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.input-group {
    display: table;
    order-collapse: separate;
}
.input-group-addon{
    border: 1px solid #333;
    display: table-cell;
    height: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add "line-height" propery to a value equal to "height". in your case "50px":

```
.input-group-addon {
    border: 1px solid #333333;
    display: table-cell;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: yes this did work! (sorry for the very late reply)
all the other solutions just seemed weird..

Comment: @ActoneDev: Thank you for your answer. Please if for you, mine is the right answer, "accept" it clicking on the mark sign under vote number. Maybe you does not have enough reputation to do it now, but maybe you'll be able to come back in the future. Thank you. :-)

Answer (score 0):

as an option and can be so

```
.input-group-addon {
    border: 1px solid #333333;
    display: table-cell;
    line-height: 1px;
    padding: 20px 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just giving it a width and height? I don't see this div containing a lot of content (maybe a word or two at most)

```
.input-group span{
    width: 100px;
    height:37px;
 }
```

[***SEE DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/X7pa3/3/)